ntfy crashed in AlpineLinux with OpenRC
Hello I have set up an "ntfy" server with an Alpine Linux as a base. If I run "ntfy" as a system service via OpenRC, then the service crashes.
The log has the following error message:
2024/05/24 22:09:33 INFO Listening on :80[http], ntfy 2.11.0, log level is INFO (tag=startup)

2024/05/24 22:09:33 FATAL listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied (exit_code=1)

listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied

There seems to be a permissions issue with the startup process in OpenRC. If I run "ntfy serve" as the root user, then the service runs without any problems.
Maybe someone has an idea to solve the problem, thanks.
